# How to run vNext web api on IIS7

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core, dnx

i'm getting started with asp.net vNext and i've found something that i cant understand if is a limitation on the DNX or if is something still not fixed.

When i'm publishing a simple webapi, as simply as the the default VS2015C template, my IIS 7 says:
**IIS 7.5 or higher is required.**

Is there some workarround or is really a limitation?

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest community standup, the HELIOS integration between IIS and asp.net 5 was stopped. Ongoing the only server provided by MS is kestrel. You have to start and integrate kestrel into IIS by reverse proxying it.
This is quite normal in the Unix world and the .net team  had to reduce the maintenance effort here.

Answering your question: Considering the [Announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/69) I think practical usage in an Windows Environment via [HttpPlatformHandler](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/httpplatformhandler/httpplatformhandler-configuration-reference) is only possible IIS8+.

Comment: This is not true - there will be integration between IIS and kestrel. Here is more details https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/69

Comment: Well ... like the announcement describes, the HELIOS integration is deprecated. Therefore, no native integration into IIS. Like the announcement describes we can use the HttpPlatformHandler to launch an EXTERNAL executable (here kestrel) and reverse proxy the traffic. That is what I desribe above (without using the term HttpPlatformHandler ... which I did not knew ;)).

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET 5 never has and never will support IIS 7 (Windows Vista and Windows 2008 both have IIS 7 only); IIS 7.5 and higher is actually required to bootstrap the dnx. If you want to work with ASP.NET 5 you must be running a Windows 7 or higher client OS or a Windows 2008 R2 or higher server OS.